# To run a python function with multiple parameters

Tags: python, for-loop, time-series

I have a function here:

```
def ROC(dfH, n):  
    M = dfH['Close'].diff(n - 1)  
    N = dfH['Close'].shift(n - 1)  
    ROC = pd.Series(M / N, name = 'ROC_' + str(n))  
    dfH = dfH.join(ROC)  
    return dfH
```

With the above function I want to make multiple columns by changing the value of n so i run the code

```
a = (4, 8)
for j in a:
    ROC(dfH, n=a)
```

which gets to be wrong. please help
thanks in advance.

`

Comment: Except of the formatting what's wrong with your code?

Comment: Unable to make columns with different values of a

Comment: You are not using the return value of `ROC` anywhere. You might want to print it or store it in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = (4, 8)
for j in a:
    ROC(dfH, n=a)
               ^
```

You are using **a** instead of **j** in the for loop.